# Chart.js multiple series with same scale

Tags: chart.js, stackedbarseries, lineseries

I have a stacked bar chart with an unstacked line chart combo chart using Chart.js.  I need the stacked bars and unstacked lines to appear on the same axis.  It doesn't appear that I can do this, so I put them on different axes so that one could be stacked and the other not (e.g., overlay a capacity line over production of different parts).  However, if they must be on different axes, then I need them to have the same scale.  I could not find a way to force the axes to have the same scale automatically, so I am forced to try to compute my own scale and set them each to that.  This isn't ideal and I would prefer if I could just use a setting to force them to use the same scale.  Is this possible?

Here is a post that is basically the same question as I am: [Chart.js place both series on same scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108735/chart-js-place-both-series-on-same-scale) The only difference is that I need to stack my bar series which prevents me from using the same axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to do, but it is possible to create a stacked bar chart with an un-stacked line chart combo on the same axis.

Here is an example configuration showing how do to it.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      type: 'line',
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
      borderWidth: 2,
      fill: false,
      data: [5, 3, 4, 10, 8, 9, 2]
    }, {
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
      stack: 'Stack 0',
      data: [2, 4, 1, 3, 7, 3, 6],
      borderColor: 'white',
      borderWidth: 2
    }, {
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 3',
      backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green,
      stack: 'Stack 0',
      data: [7, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Stacked Bar and Unstacked Line Combo Chart'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a working [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/wJqyeg) as well.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know that you could group stacks that way (new feature).  This solves my problem!

Comment: The problem is If you add a second lines then those line will stack no ?